# What is a less litigious synonym for "plaintiff"?

Tags: synonyms, north-american-english

I'd like to say something like "the complainer" for a one-off incident where a person complained about another person, but without implying that they complain habitually (i.e. complainer), and without implying there were legal proceedings (i.e. plaintiff, complainant).

> **plaintiff** - the person in a legal proceeding who makes a charge of wrongdoing against another
>
> **complaintant** - the party who makes the complaint in a legal action or proceeding
>
> **complainer** - a person who makes frequent complaints usually about little things

**Example sentence:** The ____ accused Mrs. Jones of taking her keyboard. The ____ then proceeded to raise her voice at Mrs. Jones.

Comment: How about *accuser*?

Comment: Your writing emulates legal style here, why not borrow *complainant* which has less legal implications than *plaintiff*?

Comment: It's for an office incident report which is to be given to a senior manager with the aim of 1) not sounding legally serious, and 2) not painting an overly negative view of the person who raised the complaint.

Comment: @jim Accuser - it's quite serious

Comment: In your own words: " ____ ***accused*** Mrs. Jones"

Comment: "An unnamed person intimated that her (or maybe *their* if you are trying to maintain anonymity) keyboard may have been taken by Mrs. Jones."

Comment: *The complaint raiser* ...

Comment: Ok, good, then how do you refer to this unnamed person in your next sentence (without saying they/he/she/that person/and the like)?

Comment: They then proceeded to raise their voice at Mrs. Jones.

Comment: You want to make a report to a senior manager; you want the report not to sound serious enough to be legal and you don't want to the person who raised the complaint to be cast in a negative light.  Then this whole thing should be handled at a level (or several levels) below the senior manager, with only a memo to file, if any memo at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is some particular reason for withholding the person's name, I might refer to them as ***the party***, ***the offended party***, or ***the other party***.

If you wanted to be less formal you could say ***the person***, the ***offended person*** etc.

But I also see little wrong with saying ***the complainant*** for that is what they were.

Take all of the above to include the indefinite article rather than the definite, if that seems appropriate.

Comment: I'll use a mix of "the complainant" and "the other party" to avoid using the same term repeatedly in each sentence. Thank you for the suggestions

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is *the aggrieved*, defined as having suffered from unfair treatment [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aggrieved).